# Best practice to designate image file as "primary"

Tags: php, image, exif

I am building a site where users will be able to upload some images as display them as part of their profile. I would like to allow them to make one of their images the "primary" image to be displayed as their main profile picture.

All I would need is to tag that image with some metadata which can be read later, but what is the best standard method for doing this? Is it exif data? Is it appending something to the filename? Is it something else?

Comment: i would put such details in a db. along with the other user information

Comment: Use a field in the user table defining what is his avatar... (image_id if you store image information in db or image_path if you don't)